# Dnd avatar: how to get wysiwyg-preview on dragOver?

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo, drag-and-drop, dojo-dnd

We've got a request from a customer to support the following scenario:

- on a page we have a container: `div` element which is at the same time `dojo.dnd.Source`.
- inside the container we've got 9 `div` elements with similar content: 2 buttons and 2 comboboxes
- a user should be able to define the sequence of those 9 `div` elements by simply dragging them around inside the container.

The task is to present a possible layout preview while dragging.

Will appreciate any ideas.

Comment: The easiest thing was to go pure CSS way. Dojo sets dojoDndItemOver class, so the idea was to change the width of a div.dojoDndItemOver and to set padding. Worked partly: once  in a while worked as expected, but once in a while was blinking/jumping badly. Moreover, in this approach were difficult to exclude div.dojoDndItemAnchor elements.

Comment: Currently I am trying to use eventHandlers to do the series of drops, and to roll back on onDndCancel. Not even sure that I'm going the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on your comment and first attempt at this solution, I humbly suggest the following:

If things are being animated and sensitive to mouse pointer changes you should separate the two:

- Leave the element with the drag/drop event subscription (the parent) alone. Do not change its appearance ever.
- Create an element (the child) inside this element that gets animated, but does not affect its parent.
- The parent can be transparent.

Can this be of help?

Comment: Thank you, Jonas. For the time being we stick to the CSS-based solution.